# MULE - Change precedence of variables from application properties and VM arguments

Tags: mule, vmargs

Is there a way to change the precedence of application of properties file to VM arguments in Mule application?

If not, how should we implement so that code checks for VM args first if not available then check application.properties file?

something like,

```
if (propFromVMArgs != null)
{...}
else
{//use property from application.property file...}
```

Comment: i am also having same issue

Comment: @AdityaTomar Did you try it out anyother approach? I'm trying to create a custom class to get the value from vm args if null then pick from application property and use those methods in where ever places I need them. But this is a tedious process to updated this logic everywhere in the project. So seeking someother way to get this done